how to give access to my tmux session?
I create a session with which I can log in and out, but other users do not even see it, I tried to change the rights of the session, but nothing happened
artem@server:/home/stop$ tmux ls
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1003/default
stop@server:~$ tmux ls
nest: 1 windows (created Thu May 30 17:56:44 2024)

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-31-generic x86_64)

"I tried to change the rights of the session, but nothing happened" how? What distro/version of Linux? [edit] your question - don't add to the comment trail.

TL;DR - this is related to the path and permissions of the server socket tmux uses.
As you may see, by default tmux stores the server socket in the directory /tmp/tumx-$UID/default, where $UID is the 4-digit user ID.
So when you run tmux ls as the user 1003 (artem), it will look at the default socket /tmp/tmux-1003/default.
If the server is created with another user (let's say user 1002), you have to specify the socket path, like this:
artem@server:~$ tmux -S /tmp/tmux-1002/default ls

You could also specify the socket path as user-independent when creating your tmux session, like this:
stop@server:~$ tmux -S /tmp/shared-session

And then attach to it with:
artem@server:~$ tmux -S /tmp/shared-session attach

If you still run into permission issues, try the more detailed steps below.
A more detailed solution
Inspired by this answer, I would suggest that you create a specific tmux group, and direct the server socket to a directory with the permissions of this group.
So first add a tmux group:
$ sudo addgroup --system tmux

Create a directory /var/tmux for the group (where you can direct tmux socket), assign the group, and set the proper permissions:
$ sudo mkdir /var/tmux
$ sudo chgrp tmux /var/tmux
$ sudo chmod g+ws /var/tmux

Add the user you want to have access to the shared tmux sessions to the tmux group:
$ sudo usermod -aG tmux user1
$ sudo usermod -aG tmux user2

Now you create a shared session with:
$ tmux -S /var/tmux/shared-session

Attach to it from another account with:
$ tmux -S /var/tmux/shared-session attach 

